# dd linux command to create a clone image

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I created an image based on an ssd card with ubuntu 16, the SSD card is 120gb. During the process I compressed the output file with gz and I got an image file of about 3.5gb. All good but the problem is that when I'm trying to flash a 128gb sd card using (Raspberry Imager or balenaEtcher I got an error finishing the process that there is no enough space.

Is `dd` command right tool for creating the image?

Why the command cloned also the empty space? because in my ssd card I'm using very little space not the 120gb?

Comment: `dd` is low level and make an image of the entire disk, even with no datas. If you need to save space, better use `rsync` or `borgbackup` if you need this for a backup

Comment: Thanks @GillesQuénot so there is no way of option to tell dd, hey just clone the system not the empty space? I will check on rsync documentation

Comment: No. That's why I recommend `borgbackup`, it's better than `rsync` for backups

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a backup, [`borgbackup`](https://www.borgbackup.org/) is what you need.

Some nice features:

- compression
- de-duplication
- encryption

With this, you backup only the data you have, not the free space. And with compression/de-duplications, size is small and it's fast.